# Oracle Apex Team Collaboration

Tags: oracle-apex

I've started learning a new stack (oracle-apex-18), and I have a team that is more likely to contribute to my projects. How do I go about having a structure team collaboration in oracle-apex?

This is for team collaboration on oracle-apex projects. I've tried using the team collaboration features, however, this does not solve if someone has to contribute some sort of PLSQL code.

Answer (score 2):

You have to have your database source code (PLSQL and SQL scripts) for all packages, triggers and etc in source files in a Git (or SVN) repository.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about source code control, I suggest something like https://liquibase.org/ which should do the trick.

If you are looking for something more in the Git/Free aspect, what I do is export the applications as a ZIP file and upload them to git. The same for CSS, JavaScript a Pl/SQL scripts. I know it is more manual than it should but it works fine for us.

As of today, at the [Oracle APEX Road Map](https://apex.oracle.com/en/learn/resources/roadmap/) they are planning to integrate the tool with GIT in a more direct way, so maybe it would be worth to wait for that